# PHP MYSQL Opposite selection

Tags: php, mysql

```
$line = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clips, userclips 
WHERE userclips.userid='$id' AND 
userclips.clipid=clips.id ORDER BY clips.title");
```

Which returns all the clips associated with a particular user. However I'm stumped trying to write a query that will do the exact opposite; select all clips that aren't associated with that user.

I have tried this:

```
$line = @mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM clips, userclips 
WHERE userclips.userid!='$id' AND userclips.clipid=clips.id ORDER BY clips.title");
```

Which does return clips not associated with that user, however it misses clips that aren't associated with any users.

Please help if you can :)

Comment: You should investigate not using the mysql_* functions. Go for PDO or or mysqli_* at the very least.

Comment: Do you want to return a particular clip or all the clips which are not associated with a user

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded, that is my first time using stackoverflow, bit overwhelmed by all the helpful responses. Thanks everyone. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $line = @mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM clips WHERE clips.id 
 NOT IN (SELECT clipid FROM userclips WHERE userid='$id') ORDER BY clips.title");
```

Answer (score 1):

Returns all the clips and user information not associated with specific user, whose id is passed

```
SELECT * FROM clips, userclips 
WHERE userclips.userid!='$id'
ORDER BY clips.title
```

Answer (score 0):

I ll use not in for this kind of queries

```
Select * 
From clips 
Where id NOT IN  (SELECT clips.id 
                  FROM clips, userclips 
                  WHERE userclips.userid = '$id' 
                    AND userclips.clipid = clips.id 
                  ORDER BY clips.title)
```